# HTML/PHP Forms?

Tags: php, html

I need help with creating a form. It can be on blank page, I just need forms on a page.

example : NAME _______

And I would like the filled form be stored on the server so I can print them.

Print example: NAME firstname lastname

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say we have two files. The first file, called `index.html` is a pure-HTML page that displays a form. The second file is called `process.php` which handles the data from the form server-side.

`index.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Example Form</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <form action="process.php" method="POST">
            <label for="firstname_input">First Name:</label><br>
            <input type="text" id="firstname_input" name="firstname" /><br>

            <label for="lastname_input">Last Name:</label><br>
            <input type="text" id="lastname_input" name="lastname" /><br>
        </form>

        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </body>
</html>
```

`process.php`:

```
<?php

if (!isset($_POST['firstname']) || !isset($_POST['lastname']))
{
    die("Error! Both the firstname and lastname must be specified.")
}

$firstName = $_POST['firstname'];
$lastName = $_POST['lastname'];

echo sprintf("You specified a first name of '%s' and a last name of '%s'.", htmlspecialchars($firstName), htmlspecialchars($lastName));
```

From here, you can store `$firstName` and `$lastName` in a file or a database (such as MySQL) to store them permanently, but that seems to be beyond the scope of the question. If you choose to store them in MySQL, something like this should work:

```
$sql = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO user (first_name, last_name) VALUES (:first_name, :last_name)");
$sql->bindValue(':first_name', $firstName);
$sql->bindValue(':last_name', $lastName);

if (!$sql->execute())
{
    die("Failed to add user to database.");
}
```

You didn't specify how or where you wanted to store the data, and there are many other ways to store it, but this is how you'd do it in MySQL.

Comment: Your HTML is invalid and your PHP has a massive XSS security hole in it. It also doesn't store anything as the question requests.

Comment: I've now addressed these things in my edit. Thanks. This wasn't meant to be production code, but rather, an example of how to transfer data between a form and a PHP application. But, you're right, these things should have been addressed, and now, are :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code for it :

```
<form>
    First name:<br>
    <input type="text" name="firstname">
    <br>
    Last name:<br>
    <input type="text" name="lastname">
</form>
```

For getting that values in next page u can use ,

```
action = POST
```

this parameter in form tag.